# How to remove the first 3 bytes and last one byte from s64 value?

Tags: c++, c, linux, types, casting

code :

```
s64 end_time;
struct timespec ts;
getrawmonotonic(&ts);
end_time = timespec_to_ns(&ts);
```

How to remove the first three bytes from `end_time` and last one byte from it??
I want to store it in a uint32. 
could someone tell me how to do that??

```
uint32 latency;
fscanf(fp, "%lu\n", latency);  //fp  is reading the end_time and storing in latency.
latency = (uint32) (latency >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: With last byte, do you mean the least significant or most significant one?

Comment: Define 'first' and 'last' (in either case, one of them is not going to matter at all for your purpose).

Comment: Don't put answer in question. Mark the answer that helped you instead.

Comment: In your edited question you need to define latency as `s64` otherwise the data you seek is lost. Also: `fscanf(fp, "%lld", latency);`

Comment: after that shall i convert ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I can also use int64_t instead of s64 ??

Comment: Yes. That should work.

Comment: format specifier for uint32 ?? Is it %lu ??

Comment: Yes. But you need to read it as `int64` (long long) and the format specifier for that is `%lld`.

Comment: if I give %lld then it is showing warning !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
u32 end_time32 = (u32) (end_time >> 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Depending on your definition of `first` and `last` byte it could also be:

```
u32 end_time32 = (u32) (end_time >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Example:

```
s64 end_time = 0x1234567890ABCDEF;
u32 end_time32 = (u32) (end_time >> 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

// end_time32 is now: 0x34567890

s64 end_time = 0x1234567890ABCDEF;
u32 end_time32 = (u32) (end_time >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

// end_time32 is now: 0x7890ABCD
```

**Edit**

After your updated question:

```
s64 latency;
fscanf(fp, "%lld", latency);  //fp  is reading the end_time and storing in latency.
u32 latency32 = (uint32) (latency >> 8) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: what will happen if you give  & 0xFFFFFFFF ??

Comment: `&` is the logical `AND` operator. `0xFFFFFFFF` in binary is all 1's (32 of em to be specific). 1 & 1 yields 1. 1 & 0 yields 0. So both values has to be 1 for the result to be 1. Since you want to truncate a 64-bit value to 32-bit then you want to make sure there are only 32-bits of singificant information in the resulting number. `0xFFFFFFFF` makes sure that the first 32-bits retain their value and other 32-bits are zeroed.

Comment: @user3615655 Your new code in the question doesn't make any sense. You're masking a value of type `uint32` (which is not a standard type, but I assume it's a 32-bit unsigned integer).

Comment: The mask (`& 0xFFFFFFFF`) makes only sense in parentheses. Currently, you're masking the value already cast to `uint32_t` which is by definition 32 bits large...

Comment: is it possible to read the s64 by uint32 variable ??   could you tell me the other alternative ??

Comment: In your edited question you need to define latency as `s64` otherwise the data you seek is lost. Also: `fscanf(fp, "%lld", latency);`

Comment: If I do as you said then first three bytes and last one byte will be removed. isnt it ??

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "first" and "last" you mean "most significant" and "least significant", respectively.

I.e., you have the 8 bytes:

```
76543210
```

and want to map it to the 4 bytes:

```
4321
```

This is easiest done by a shift, a mask, and a (truncating) cast:

```
const uint32_t time32 = (uint32_t) ((end_time >> 8) & 0xffffffff);
```

The mask is very likely to be optimized out by the compiler but makes it very clear what's going on.

Comment: Why do you have to mask the result before casting?

Comment: @leemes I don't, it's just to be very clear what's going on. Hence my comment about optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **bit shifting**. You have to shift the value 8 bits (= 1 byte) to the right, which is done with the `>>` operator:

```
uint32_t t = (uint32_t)(end_time >> 8);
//                               ^^
//                          bit-shifting
```

In the following, the bytes are visualized for a better understanding. If the value `end_time` consisted of eight bytes with the symbolic values `A B C D E F G H`, what you want is `D E F G`:

```
end_time:                     A B C D E F G H
end_time >> 8:                0 A B C D E F G
(uint32_t)(end_time >> 8):            D E F G
```